# Славянские женские имена: так были или нет?

Tags: имена-собственные

Прочитала тут в одном обсуждении, что, мол, у славян не было женских имен, а женщин звали по отчеству (отсюда Ярославна в "Слове о полку Игореве"). Но как же тогда быть с русскими сказками? Как же Любава в "Садко", как всякие Забавы Путятишны и т.д.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Про имена  - это скорее всего я писал.
Не буду искать где, но там смысл высказывания был совершенно другим. 
Я гооворил о том, что ***некрестильные*** женские имена были совершенно не в ходу за пределами сеймейного общения. Основным "именем" женщины было отчество. Речь шла о периоде до Крещения Руси, в меньшей степени - до Ига.

По поводу ссылки Людмилы. 
Псевдославянские имена типа Людмила(;)), Светлана или Снежана (и вообще почти весь Ваш список) придуманы поэтами-славянофилами не ранее XVII-XVIII веков. Не надо читать сонники как источник авторитетных этимологических изысканий... 
Возможно, где-то употреблялись подобные прозвища-эпитеты, но функций идентификации или персонификации они не несли.

> Но как же тогда быть с русскими сказками? Как же Любава в "Садко", как всякие Забавы Путятишны и т.д.?

Именно так. Любава в Садко персонаж не исторический, про источники легенды о Садко я тоже где-то тут писал. А Забава Путятична - это то самое прозвище-эпитет. Хотя, повторюсь, речь шла о тенденции, какие-то исключения я допускаю.

Comment: to@behemothus Интересно бы почитать что-либо авторитетное, подтверждающее Ваше мнение.

Comment: Ссылку привела первую попавшуюся, она, конечно, неавторитетна, просто любопытна.Авторитетна будет "Повесть временных лет".Но там будут женские только  имена княгинь, а они часто как раз неславянские - Рогнеда - полоцкое,Малуша, мать Владимира,от еврейского Малка (он же внебрачный сын, от дочери еврейского раввина). А простые женские имена - в берестяных грамотах. Есть у Балашова в книге "Господин Великий Новгород".Имена, похожие на прозвища, но ведь имена так и давались - по каким-то качествам. А христианские и вовсе все были иностранныеhttp://www.stavrosha.ru/content/o-drevnerusskih-imenah/

Comment: >Интересно бы почитать что-либо авторитетное, подтверждающее Ваше мнение.  
  
Какое из?
Если про происхождение псевдославянских имен, то это фает достачтоно известный. 
А что касается мой оценки ***роли*** славянских женских, то я читал что-то на эту тему, но вполне в состоянии сделать этот вывод и самомтоятельно. Много вы знаете достоверных исторических женских имен славянского происхождения того периода? Хотя бы княжеских? О то ж. В то же время всех княжей мы знаем именно по славянским именам, хотя все они были крещены и имели канонические греческие имена.

Answer (score 11):

Древнерусские женские имена сохранились на берестяных грамотах Новгорода, Старой Руссы, Пскова, Смоленска и из других мест. Прочитав несколько материалов по этому вопросу (расшифровка берестяных грамот), я выписал имена женщин 11-14 вв, они разделяются на календарные христианские и некалендарные славянские.
Начнем с последних.
Гостята, имя женщины с новг. гр. 009, одной из первых. Женщина жалуется некоему Васильве, что муж ее выгнал ни с чем, привел в дом новую жену, и просит приехать, разобраться по-доброму.
Марена, новгородка, и ее дочь, по прозвищу Коса Великая.
Передслава, Милуша, Ноздрька (?), Сторонька, Милка, Страхота, Безубая, Миляна, Нежка, Втора, Неделька, Чудка... Имена разных форм и употреблений, но это реальные исторические имена женщин и девушек, записанные на бересте.
Христианские имена : Анастасия, Мария, Христина, Ефимия, София, Яна, Евдокия, Ульяна, Федосья, Феврония, Марфа, Домна, Анна, Фекла, Катерина, Улита, Ефросиния, Акулина, Антонина, Евгения, Фетинья и др.
Разумеется, женщин также называли по отчествам, именам и прозвищам их мужей, собственным прозвищам и тд.

[Одна из ссылок](http://elar.urfu.ru/handle/10995/1951), там имеется адрес небольшого файла пдф, из которого я почерпнул наибольшую информацию. Другой источник - одна из лекций А.А.Зализняка, имеется в сети.

Comment: Прекрасный ответ!

Answer (score 6):

Где это Вы прочитали? У Ярославны есть имя - Ефросинья. И у всех были, даже двойные: ложные для общего достояния( Злоба, Бяка), чтоб отогнать злые силы, и тайное настоящее - ласковое и красивое, с двумя основами:Всеслава,Добромила,Веселина ,Велимира,Богумила, Болеслава. Потом церковь многие из них с языческими корнями запретила, а жаль.

Вот здесь почитайте:
[Происхождение и значение славянских имен | sonnik-online.net](http://www.sonnik-online.net/imena/po/proishojdeniyu_slavyanskie.html)

Answer (score 6):

Не  могло  так  быть,  чтобы  у  девочки  было  только  узкосемейное  имя.  А  подружки  её  как  звали ?  А  если  даже  за  пределами  семьи  как-то  звали,  то  это  имя  и  есть.  Они  ж  не  виноваты,  что  летописи  ими  не  интересовались.  А  Малуша,  мать  Владимира,  разве  не  имя ?

Comment: Да уж, если ребенок народился, ползать и бегать начал, то имя у него было в любом случае, даже у девочки, даже у дочери простых общинников или холопов. Сомнений нет никаких.